# ir.actions.act_window displays a list of purchase orders

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I want to allow user to press a button and display a list of Purchase Orders (specifically the IDs included in `pos.ids`).

If I include this code in the action controller of the button I get the list:

```
            return {
                    'name': 'Purchase Order List',
                    'view_type': 'form',
                    'view_mode': 'tree',
                    'view_id': self.env.ref('purchase.purchase_order_tree').id,
                    'res_model': 'purchase.order',
                    'domain':[('id','in',pos.ids)],
                    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                    'target': 'current',
            }
```

However, in that list I can not click on the specific Purchase Order and open the form view. Why? What shall be done to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified the `view_mode` as tree only, If you want to see the form view of the record also have to specify the `form view`.And you don't have to specify the `view_id` in this case.

Change your code like this and try.

```
  return {
            'name': 'Purchase Order List',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',  # Changed
            'res_model': 'purchase.order',
            'domain':[('id','in',pos.ids)],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'current',
        }
```